# how to assign a vector to a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to assign a vector to a cell using the following command. but last line of the following for loop doesn't work and add [] elements to the cell.

```
for i=1:Nf
   WM_bits{1,i}(1,1:4)=dec2bin(encoded_lengths(1,i),4);
   total_frame_bit_length=13*encoded_lengths(1,i);
   WM_bits{1,i(1,end+1:end+total_frame_bit_length)=reshape(encoded_bits{1,i},1[]);
   WM_bits{1,i}(1,end+1:end+13)=encoded_signs{1,i};
end
```

Comment: encoded_signs{1,i} is a binary vector.(contains 0 and 1s)

Comment: Please  mention the given error message.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access vector within a cell which is not possible.
Try
     WM_bits{1,i}=encoded_signs(1,i);